# Assume that x, y, and z are Matlab arrays, plot the function e^(-x)sin(x) across the interval [0. 4pi]

Tags: matlab, graph, numerical-methods

```
x=linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
y=sin(x);
z=exp(-x);
```

Given that x, y, and z are already initialized, how do I write a function that plots exp(-x)sin(x) across the interval [0, 4pi] without additional calls to sin or exp? Just need some help getting started.

Thanks to @Rayryeng for getting me started. I believe the following command more closely satisfies the question's specifications.

```
plot(x+x, z.*z.*y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've already created arrays for `sin` and `exp` stored in `y` and `z` respectively.  These arrays were created on the same domain as `x`.  You just need to multiply both arrays together element-wise and plot the graph.  It's as simple as doing:

```
plot(x, z.*y);
```

Here, `.*` stands for element-wise multiplication.  If you were to do `z*y`, MATLAB interprets this as **matrix multiplication** where `z` and `y` are interpreted to be matrices.  This is obviously not what you want.

However, your array of `x` only contains points from 0 to `2*pi`.  If you want to plot this from 0 to `4*pi`, you have to modify your call to `linspace`:

```
x=linspace(0, 4*pi, 100); %// Change
y=sin(x);
z=exp(-x);
plot(x, z.*y);
```

Now, `x` will contain 100 points between 0 to `4*pi`.  For more information on basic MATLAB operations, check out this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html.  What you have asked falls into the basic realms of array and matrix operations.

## Edit

In the spirit of your question, we can't modify `linspace`.  You did something clever where we can simply scale our values of `x` by 2 or adding with `x` so that we have points going from 0 to `2*pi` to 0 to `4*pi`.  Also, if we scale our points by 2, this means that our input argument into the function must also be scaled by 2.  So, the final function we need to plot is:

```
y = exp(-2x)*sin(2x)
```

Noting your hint, `exp(-2x) = exp(-x-x) = exp(-x)exp(-x)`.  Further, note that `sin(2x)` performs a **compression** by a factor of 2 (tip of the hat goes to knedlsepp for noticing my blunder).  Due to the periodic nature of `sin(x)`, we know that elements will repeat after `2*pi`, and so if you want to go to `4*pi`, simply subsample `y` by a factor of 2 and then append these same elements to a new vector.  Therefore, our expression for the function simplifies to:

```
y = exp(-x)exp(-x)sin(2x)
```

This leads to the answer alluded to knedlsepp:

```
plot(x+x, z.*z.*[y(1:2:end) y(1:2:end)]);
```

As such, you should consider changing your edits to match this answer instead.  It isn't quite right with respect to the `sin(x)` part in your code.

Comment: Thanks just getting used to matlab!

Comment: @user53008 - My pleasure :) Keep asking questions.  That's how you learn quickly!

Comment: @user53008 - I've added more information on what `.*` is doing.  One of the most basic things you need to know is the difference between the `*`, `/` operations in comparison to the `.*` and `./` operations.

Comment: I left out something from the question, a hint that says exploit the fact that sine has period 2pi and that e^(a+b)=e^a(e^b). Does the question mean we cannot modify call to linspace? I don't see how to plot across 4pi without modifying linspace

Comment: @user53008 - Ah yes, your modification will work.  Nicely done!

Comment: @rayryeng: I don't get it. Maybe I'm confused, but the **Edit** part doesn't seem to give the same result.

Comment: @knedlsepp - I'm aware.  I just haven't had the time to fix it.  I wrote this longer explanation about how to achieve what the OP wants, but I haven't had time to actually post it.  What I'll do is just revert the changes back to what I had before, and when I have time to fix it, I will.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking along the lines of: `plot(2*x, z.*z.*[y(1:2:end),y(1:2:end)]);`.

Comment: @knedlsepp - It also seems that you're constantly correcting my posts.  You should get a badge for that.

Comment: @knedlsepp - Yes!  That's it.

Comment: @rayryeng: I swear it's just a coincidence. ;-)

Comment: @knedlsepp - I've changed the post to suit your comments.  I had a very long explanation, and I just removed it and put in what we've talked about here.